# Not getting birth date while integrating Facebook in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using js sdk for login with facebook.
I already set all the permissions and set all the field at function calling time but I didn't get user birthday date.

I am using permission parameters array for scope and fields array for fields retrive

I am using following code :-

```
var permissions = [
          'email',
          'user_likes',
          'friends_likes',
          'user_about_me',
          'friends_about_me',
          'user_birthday',
          'friends_birthday',
          'user_education_history',
          'friends_education_history',
          'user_hometown',
          'friends_hometown',
          'user_relationships',
          'friends_relationships',
          'user_relationship_details',
          'friends_relationship_details',
          'user_location',
          'friends_location',
          'user_religion_politics',
          'friends_religion_politics',
          'user_website',
          'friends_website',
          'user_work_history',
          'friends_work_history'
          ].join(',');

// Specify the user fields to query the OpenGraph for.
// Some values are dependent on the user granting certain permissions
        var fields = [
          'id',
          'name',
          'first_name',
          'middle_name',
          'last_name',
          'gender',
          'locale',
          'languages',
          'link',

          'third_party_id',
          'installed',
          'timezone',
          'updated_time',
          'verified',
          'age_range',
          'bio',
          'birthday',
          'cover',
          'currency',
          'devices',
          'education',
          'email',
          'hometown',
          'interested_in',
          'location',
          'political',
          'payment_pricepoints',
          'favorite_athletes',
          'favorite_teams',
          'picture',
          'quotes',
          'relationship_status',
          'religion',
          'significant_other',
          'video_upload_limits',
          'website',
          'work'
          ].join(',');

function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {

                    if(response != ''){
                        var r = response.authResponse;
                        var userID = r.userID;

                        getUserInfo();
                    }

            }, {scope: permissions , return_scopes: true});            
        }
 function getUserInfo() {   
                FB.api('/me',  {fields: fields},
                function(response) {

                console.log("User details of     data"+JSON.stringify(response));
    });
        }
```

Comment: I have the same issue...